# How to set closest form name from inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to set the name of form inside my directive. But unable to do so as I get an error TypeError: undefined is not a function. Can you help me fix this?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB43L/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <form>
  <input type="text" value="my value" my-element/>
</form>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myElement', function() {
return{
    restrict:'A',
    compile:function(element, attrs)
    {
        console.log("Hello Element");
        console.log(element.closest("form").attr("name"));
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You are trying to use jQuery functions in an angular library. You either need to include jQuery or use the functions that are available from jQLight: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 3):

`element` is not a jQuery element, so you can't call jQuery methods on it.  Fortunately, there's an easier way:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myElement', function() {
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        compile:function(element, attrs)
        {
            console.log("Hello Element");
            console.log(element[0].form);
        }
    }
});
```

Every HTMLElementObject has a `form` attribute that points to the encapsulating form.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB43L/3/) (note that you needed to add `ng-app="myApp"` to the parent div element.

Comment: yeah you're able to locate the form but cant use addClass(), etc functions on it.